# Permission denied running job in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am trying to run my first job in AWS Glue, but I am encountering the following error: "An error occurred while calling o103.pyWriteDynamicFrame. /run-1679066163418-part-r-00000 (Permission denied)".

The error message indicates that the permission has been denied. I am using an IAM Role that has AmazonS3FullAccess, AWSGlueServiceRole, and even AdministratorAccess. Although I understand that this is not ideal for security reasons, I added this policy to ensure that the IAM Role is not the issue.

I have attempted to use different sources (such as DynamoDB and S3) and targets (such as Redshift and Datacatalog), but I consistently receive the same error. Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which part of the code exactly causes this error ?

Comment: I think it's one of the last lines.This is the log error: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fb7HsbFl2eRbogqhh0BlBnzdkvInypKx0I3IPQ8MV2o/edit

Comment: And this is the script created (I didn't write it, I just used the visual to create the ETL): https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gsp5g0IiUv0knY4JsuuwpL-SSfI48oCiDC6ogK9z1lw/edit

Comment: @LadislaoCsulak were you able to fix this? I'm having a similar problem while using PyMC in a Glue Job